# React-native getting xml data from mssql using fetch request

Tags: php, react-native

I'm working on a script that should call a post request to get (XML) data from the Microsoft SQL server using fetch() and PHP as an endpoint

react native (fetch)

```
function test(){
  fetch('http://blahblah.com/gol/partner/getXMLfromDatabase.php', {
  method: 'POST',
  headers: {
    Accept: 'text/plain',
    'Content-Type': 'text/plain'
  },
  body:{
    emp_number: '20209',
  }
})
  .then((response) => response.text())
  .then((data) => console.log(data));
}
```

getXMLfromDatabase.php

```
<?php
    header('Content-Type: text/plain');
    $gecolEmployee = $_GET['emp_number'];

    $serverName = "HOST"; 
    $connectionInfo = array( "Database"=>"gecol");
    $conn = sqlsrv_connect( $serverName, $connectionInfo);
        $query = "SELECT * FROM readers WHERE emp_number=?";
        $result = sqlsrv_query($conn, $query, array($gecolEmployee));
        $row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($result);
        if( $conn ) {
            echo $row['xml'];
        }else{
            echo "Error.<br />";
            die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));
        }
?>
```

console log (Error)

```
[Unhandled promise rejection: TypeError: Network request failed]
at node_modules\whatwg-fetch\dist\fetch.umd.js:535:17 in setTimeout$argument_0
at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Core\Timers\JSTimers.js:214:12 in _allocateCallback$argument_0
at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Core\Timers\JSTimers.js:112:14 in _callTimer
at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Core\Timers\JSTimers.js:357:16 in callTimers
at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\BatchedBridge\MessageQueue.js:417:4 in __callFunction
at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\BatchedBridge\MessageQueue.js:114:6 in __guard$argument_0
at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\BatchedBridge\MessageQueue.js:368:10 in __guard
at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\BatchedBridge\MessageQueue.js:113:4 in callFunctionReturnFlushedQueue
```

Comment: I see no error.. [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: @Ron I have just updated the question sorry i forget to add the console log

Comment: `Network request failed` suggests that you have a network issue from the SOURCE where you initiate the connection to the DESTINTION. You can check manually with netcat or telnet if the IP and port are accessible